# What is the purpose of '!= render'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I discovered the following statement in a haml template:

```
!= render partial: 'path/to/partial'
```

What is the purpose of `!=` in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used for Unescaping HTML.

example:

`= "<Hello>"` will give `&ltg;Hello&gt;`

but now using

`!= "<Hello>"` will give `<Hello>`